# java EOFException because of copy or rename file

Tags: java

This is question is about java serialize .
firstly, I paste my code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Admin implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 613659699548582156L;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{class:'Admin'" +
                ", user:'" + user + '\'' +
                ", password:'" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Admin(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Admin() {

    }

    public String getUser() {

        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        Admin admin = (Admin) o;
        return  (user != null ? user.equals(admin.getUser()) : admin.getUser() == null) &&
                (password != null ? password.equals(admin.getPassword()) : admin.getPassword() == null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //write object
//        try {
//            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Admin.class.getClassLoader().getResource("admin.out").getPath()));
//            Admin a = new Admin("longlongago", "longlongago");
//            out.writeObject(a);
//            out.flush();
//            out.close();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        //read object
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(Admin.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("admin.out"));
            Admin a = (Admin) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
        at pw.loveyouforever.Model.Admin.main(Admin.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

when I copy or rename the file, it will appear a `java.io.EOFException`. **Even if I change the filename to previous name, it still appear `java.io.EOFException`.** What changed just filename, the file's data don't change. Why can't I read the object in this file?

Comment: Make sure the file is not empty.

Comment: I don't modify the file's data. I just copy or rename the file.

Comment: Before I copy or rename the file, I can read the object correctly.

Comment: At which line is the `EOFException` thrown?

Comment: Where do you change the file name? On the filesystem itself, or in your code?